# Como consigo atualizar automaticamente a tabela de 10 em 10 segundos?

Tags: javascript, sql, react

Eu tenho uma tabela com dados da base de dados, eu quero que a tabela atualize de 10 em 10 segundos mas não estou a conseguir, alguém consegue ajudar? o código é o seguinte:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';



export default function Reports() {
  const [data, setDate] = useState([])


  
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/erplnreports')
      .then((response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setDate(response.data)
      }))
  }, []);

  const arr = data.map((data, index, ) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{data.Action}</td>
        <td>{data.Result}</td>
        <td>{data.CreatedAt}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table"  >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Ação</th>
            <th scope="col">Resultado</th>
            <th scope="col">Data de Criação</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {arr}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Informe o Banco , alguns tem solução de agendamento. Explique melhor o problema , o que precisa ser atualizado e porque.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que tenha soluções mais adequadas para se fazer isso, porém acredito também que a sua pergunta se refere a como executar um código repeditamente num intervalo de tempo de 10 em 10 segundos:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //cria uma função com requisição
  const getData = () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/erplnreports')
    .then((response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setDate(response.data)
    }))
  }
  
  //invoca a requisição quando a página é carregada
  getData();
  
  //defini o intervalo de tempo em que essa função será executada repetidamente
  setInterval(() => {
    getData();
  }, 10000);
}, []);
```